# Why do emitter-degeneration resistors linearize an emitter coupled pair?

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis, current

Is there a mathematical derivation of the following curve for an emitter coupled pair with degeneration resistors? I can't seem to find anything online

[image: emitter coupled pair]

Comment: Resistors behave linearly to the inputs and BJTs respond exponentially/logarithmically (depending on viewpoint.) If the resistor value dominates, then that's more the behavior. A mathematical derivation is possible for probably any particular thing you want to know about the above circuit. But you should already know that there's a small-signal quantity called \$r_e\$ that is based on \$V_T\$ and \$I_\text{E}\$. So if the resistor is 3 times that much (or more) then most of the non-linearity has been removed.

Comment: I think IeRe can be 2.5Vt  to get <0.5% THD with 10mVpp input

Answer (score 3):

The specific equation for that curve is probably not so easy to mathematically reproduce because it's based on Gm which is a measured parameter of a real transistor. It is not a constant either. It varies with operating conditions so would actually be represented by some function which would probably be very large and messy since it's measured from the real world and not something mathematically idyllic.

But the curve is nonlinear because transconductance is non-linear.

The following is the AC circuit (hence all the grounded supplies) for a common-source amplifier but the idea is the same for common emitter, and for the differential pair (it's just done twice, one for each leg).

[image]
Microelectronic Circuits 7th Edition, Sedra & Smith

[image]

You can see that as Rs (the source/emitter resistor) gets larger, that the transconductance's influence on the gain gets drowned out. Since linear component is drowning out the nonlinear component, it gets more linear.

Comment: You can actually work it out. You get the usual thermal voltage, due to the Fermi-Dirac distribution. So that’s not what’s problematic. The problem is that you get equations of the form \$e^x + x = A\$ due to the emitter resistors. The exponential gets introduced since you have the diode current of the base-emitter junction multiplied by the emitter resistor. You need to use the product log function to solve said equations.

Comment: So to answer the question corrolary, prove how linear is  Re = 3*26mV / Ie

Comment: @user110971 I ain't no physicist or mathematician! I don't care how things  *really* work.  Only that they do.

Comment: Then how linear is it at Ie= 1mA for Re= 0 & 78 ohms?

Comment: @DKNguyen Many engineering inventions were made by people who asked how things worked. I think it is important to keep an open mind.

Comment: @user110971 I was being facetious. Unfortunately, the stuff I do has a tendency to draw me away from analog and all the calculations involved so I am shamefully bad at utilizing it. You could spend a lifetime rabbit holing in any one specific thing in math or physics and never finish nor have a chance to use it in a real application.

Comment: @DKNguyen I’ve found physics and math really useful. But I work with things that are closely connected to the physical world (CNC machines, radar / sonar, SAR etc.). You don’t need a lifetime to learn these things. A few years can get you to the graduate level in both disciplines. After all, if a physicist / mathematician can do it, how hard can it be.

Comment: @user110971 I dunno. I still have a list of a dozen math principles I want to get through and haven't even gotten through one. Namely, the derivation of Nyquist stability, ODEs, PDEs, state space, why the Jacobian works in integration, why linear algebra works in general, then there's all the actual analog electronic stuff. I've just found I've never needed to work at a level where that kind of rigour is required.

Comment: @DKNguyen - actually gm for a bipolar transistor  is usually fairly close to the theoretical value. It does vary with emitter current as indicated by theory. The base resistance will cause it to depart from the expected value.By contrast hfe is not a well defined quantity.

Comment: @DKNguyen Right. I wasn't going to write an answer originally, but since there is a bit of interest, I have provided one.

Answer (score 3):

The way to obtain the curve is to realize that we can use the small signal model for the transistor. This is because the base-emitter voltage varies very slightly when the differential input is changed due to the emitter degeneration. To calculate how slightly is complicated because the tail voltage of the differential pair changes due to the constant current. To acquire a more intuitive understanding of why this happens, consider the simpler common-emitter amplifier. Then

$$V_\mathrm{b} = R_\mathrm{E} I_\mathrm{E} + V_\mathrm{BE} = V_\mathrm{BE} + R_\mathrm{E} I_\mathrm{S} (e^{V_\mathrm{BE} / V_\mathrm{T}} - 1).$$

In this situation, a small change in the base-emitter voltage can result in a large change in the current due to the the exponential. This results in a large change in the emitter resistor voltage. So by increasing the base voltage the base-emitter voltage only increases slightly. The majority of the change comes from the increase of the emitter resistor voltage, as can be seen from the plot of the base-emitter voltage as a function of the base voltage with a 1k resistor.

[image: common-emitter]

You can see that after the current has increased enough for the emitter resistor to develop enough of a voltage drop, the base-emitter voltage becomes a linear function of the base voltage.

Now back to the differential pair. We know that the small signal base-emitter resistance taken at \$v_1 = v_2\$ is

$$r_\mathrm{e} = \frac{V_\mathrm{T}}{I_\mathrm{EE} / 2}.$$

Let \$V_\mathrm{EE}\$ be the voltage across the current source, let \$i_1\$ be the emitter current, and let \$V_\mathrm{Q}\$ be the base-emitter quiescent voltage at \$v_1 = v_2\$. Then

$$v_1 = i_1 (r_\mathrm{e} + R_\mathrm{E}) + V_\mathrm{Q} + V_\mathrm{EE} - V_\mathrm{CC}.$$

Thus

$$i_1 = \frac{v_1 - V_\mathrm{Q} - V_\mathrm{EE} + V_\mathrm{CC}}{r_\mathrm{e} + R_\mathrm{E}}.$$

Hence

$$V_\mathrm{E1} = V_\mathrm{CC} - \alpha i_1 R_\mathrm{C} = V_\mathrm{CC} - \alpha R_\mathrm{C} \frac{v_1 - V_\mathrm{Q} - V_\mathrm{EE} + V_\mathrm{CC}}{r_\mathrm{e} + R_\mathrm{E}}.$$

A similar equation can be derived for the other transistor. The output is then

$$v_\mathrm{O} = V_\mathrm{E1} - V_\mathrm{E2} = - \alpha \frac{R_\mathrm{C}}{r_\mathrm{e} + R_\mathrm{E}} (v_1 - v_2).$$

You can see that this is a linear equation. Compare this with the case without emitter degeneration, which you can find in any standard reference.

Comment: @user110971....I am not a beginner - however, without some definitions, it is not possible to follow your reasoning. What is "the voltage of a current source"? What is re (certainly NOT the small-signal B-E resistance)? What is v1? Are you combining small signal (differential) voltages with static DC voltages? Many uncertainties .....The answer of DKNguyen is much more correct and clearer!

Comment: @LvW v1 is defined in the question, the voltage of the current source is the voltage across the current source in the question, and re is the small signal resistance at v1 = v2.

Comment: @LvW There was a mistake. I forgot about the base-emitter quiescent voltage. Doesn't change the final answer though, as everything cancels out. You need to combine the small signal voltages with the static DC voltages in the differential pair. You do the same for the standard common-emitter amplifier, but it is hidden, since the superposition theorem is utilized. However you do not have an output filter in the differential pair. Hence you need to include the static voltages in the analysis. Especially without emitter degeneration, since the output is non-linear.

Comment: No, your reasoning is wrong and illogical. The last expression looks linear because re=1/gm (gm: transconductance) is a linearized small signal value. This equation remains "quasi-linear" even without emitter degeneration (RE=0). In his answer, DKNguyen arrives at the same expression - and he gives the correct interpretation: In reality, re=1/gm is a non-linear parameter which is responsible for the observed distortions, which become rather small for RE>>1/gm . That is the whole secrete behind negative feedback.

Comment: @LvW I think you have misunderstood my answer. The first part makes the exact same point you are making. The plot show how little the base-emitter voltage changes with degeneration. Only then can you assume that the base-emitter voltage is relatively constant. Hence re remains relatively constant. Anyway non of the other answers actually look at a differential pair.

Comment: There is no fundamental difference between a diff. pair and a simple emitter stage - as far as emitter degeneration is concerned. Your last formula contains the transconductance gm=1/re which is a non-lnear (however linearized) parameter.

Comment: ....that means: It is simply not true that your last equation is a "linear equation" since re=1/gm depends on the input signals....however, for small signals only we are allowed to neglect this dependence.

Answer (score 0):

The emitter resistances introduce a negative feedback--the negative feedback linearizes the transfer curve of the amplifying circuit--so the emitter resistances linearize the transfer curve of the differential pair...

Now a separate answer for each statement:

- The emitter resistor introduces a negative feedback since the output current creates a voltage drop across it that subtracts (in a series manner) from the input voltage.
- The negative feedback linearizes the transfer curve of the amplifying circuit since it decreases many times the enormous high open-loop gain of the amplifying stage. So the variations of this initially high gain (because of various reasons including the non-linearity) will be also decreased many times.

---

Inspired by the H&H "transistor man" (The Art of Electronics, 1989, Page 64, Fig. 2.5), I have drawn a conceptual picture to show how the negative feedback makes the transfer characteristic of the common-emitter stage linear.

[image: Emiter degeneration]

Here the output collector-emitter part of the transistor is emulated by a rheostat with variable resistance \$R_{CE}\$ so the stage is simply a triple voltage divider (\$R_{C1}\$, \$R_{CE}\$ and \$R_E\$) supplied by \$V_{CC}\$. "The little man's perpetual task in life" is to keep \$V_E = V_{IN}\$ by moving the  slider of the *collector-emitter rheostat* \$R_{CE}\$. For this purpose, he observes the *base-emitter zero indicator* and changes the rheostat resistance in the respective direction to zero the indicator reading.

Since the current of this circuit of three resistors in series is the same, there is the same proportion between the voltages and resistances - the ubiquitous \$V_{RC}/V_E = R_C/R_E\$ and this is the gain of the stage. It is constant, so the relation is linear.

By the way, this "man-emulated transistor" precisely equalizes \$V_E\$ to \$V_{IN}\$ (there is no \$V_{BE}\$ here)... and there is no current (\$I_B\$) drawn from the input source (the indicator is bootstrapped). Its only drawback is that it is slow...and of course, it engages a human being for this chore.

The power of this approach - to see the general idea behind the specific circuit, is that it is valid for various other implementations (FET, op-amp, etc.) For example, the *op-amp inverting* and *non-inverting* amplifiers exploit the same idea.

Comment: For an answer, you may want to expand on that. It's hand-waving as it sits now and less even than I wrote as a comment. (I kept my hand-waving as a comment. If I learn more about what the OP actually wants to learn, I may write something.) Just a thought.

Comment: @jonk I think the OP just wants to see equations where as Re increases, the significance of certain terms start to diminish so the equations become linear.

Comment: @jonk, I prefer to look at the phenomena in transistor amplifying stage from the negative feedback perspective. This gives a generalized view of the phenomena regardless of their specific implementations.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I think the hand wavey part is the assumption that negative feedback linearizes something nonlinear.

Comment: @DKNguyen, and how does the negative feedback linearizes something nonlinear? I ask you seriously...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I don't understand what you are trying to get at with that reply.

Comment: Aside the mathematical derivation that OP needs, there is a need of an intuitive explanation of this phenomenon...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Yes, but just saying feedback linearizes isn't intuitive unless you've already been around it for long enough. It's just a statement of fact. You probably need to provide some vague hand wavey example that demonstrates it in action it for it to qualify as an explanation that appeals to intuition.

Comment: @DKNguyen, OK... let's stop here. I have explained in my way the linearizing property of the negative feedback in the end of my answer above... and will expose it in more details in some more appropriate place. Now it's your turn to make it more clearly...

Comment: @DKNguyen They may. I hope they say so, if so. The large signal equations that include the resistors will be still be non-linear equations. Re-arranging the equations to isolate the non-linear portions related to \$R_\text{E}\$ would then highlight them in a way that makes it much more obvious how they go towards zero as the emitter resistor value increases relative to \$r_e\$. But the OP needs to chip in about this, I think. They are not saying much right now.